# I don't understand symmetries of the Fano plane

Tags: geometry, group-theory, finite-groups

Hello I got a picture of the Fano plane, but there are 5 points on every line. Why aren't there 3?

And I cannot see what it's symmetry group is. I have been told it's $PSL_2(7)$ but that doesn't help.

[image]

> How can I see the symmetries of the Fano plane by this or any other diagram?

---

I have now computed the line-point incidence relationship from the matrix group $GL_3(\mathbb F_2)$ and got the usual diagram [image] but I cannot see the symmetries of this at all.. so I found a nicer way to lay out the diagram but I stil can't see them

> I want to be able to read the symmetry group off of the diagram, I know a priori that it is $GL_3(\mathbb F_2)$. It would be even cooler if we could see that it's $PSL_2(\mathbb F_7)$ just by looking.

---

From suggestions in the comments I suppose that I have constructed the second fano plane diagram using $PSL_3(2)$, and shown the two diagrams equivalent.

I put the same labeling and coloring on both diagrams. The first has $C_7$ symmetry and the second has $D_{2 \cdot 3}$, which together generate:

```
gap> g:=Group((1,2,3,4,5,6,7),(1,2,5)(3,6,4),(1,5)(3,4));;
gap> StructureDescription(g); 
"PSL(3,2)"
```

I don't know how to get that without GAP. I guess these are all the symmetries of the fano plane, but I don't know how to show that either.

I just spotted another type of symmetry in the second fano plane diagram: $(6\;0)(1\;4)$ and so I can see the entirety of $PSL_2(7) = \langle(1\;2\;5)(3\;6\;4),(1\;5)(3\;4),(6\;0)(1\;4)\rangle$ from that one diagram.

> how can we see that together the $C_7$ and $D_{2 \cdot 3}$ make $GL_3(2)$ or even better $PSL_2(7)$? or how can we construct the first diagram from $PSL_2(7)$?

---

I was looking at the wikipedia page for [Klein quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_quartic) and there are dual pictures: tiling of hyperbolic plane by heptagons and triangles.. Can we use this geometry of the diagrams and the 3/7-duality to explain the isomorphism of the matrix groups?

Comment: There are three, it's just that some of the colors in the posted picture are poorly chosen so as to be barely distinguishable.

Comment: No one diagram will show all the symmetries of this plane.

Comment: oh thanks a lot! I've redrawn it with better colors.

Comment: Although it is true that the symmetry group is $PSL_2(F_7)$, it is also $GL_3(F_2)$, and it is much easier to understand the Fano plane that way. See math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/ for why these groups are the same.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer, that would be fine too - If I could see why it was any isomorphic group.

Comment: The $7$ points of the Fano plane are the nonzero vectors in $F_2^3$. The lines pass through triples of vectors which are coplanar. From this description, the $GL_3(F_2)$ symmetry is obvious; if you'll tell us what definition you are using, we can try to make them match up.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer, I have GL_3(F_2) as invertible 3x3 matrices of F_2 elements. and SL is when you restrict to determinant 1, and PSL is when you quotient out the center.

Comment: I see how you construct the fano plane from projective vectors in $\mathbb F_2^3$! thank you.

Comment: @user58512 In the case where the field has $2$ elements, what effect does restricting to det 1, or quotienting by the center, have?

Comment: @DavidSpeyer, I think it doesn't do anything but that seems weird. I guess that tells us GL_3(F_2) = PSL_3(F_2).

Comment: I think Chris Godsil is right, that no single diagram can show you all the symmetries. But your two diagrams together show a lot of the symmetries.  Your second, triangular picture shows that all 6 of the symmetries of the triangle (the identity, two rotations, and two reflections) give symmetries of the Fano plane. Your first, colorful picture exhibits a cyclic group of order 7 acting on the Fano plane (by rotating the picture). The subgroup of Fano symmetries generated by these two subgroups obviously has order at least $6\cdot7=42$, but I expect it's actually the full 168-element group.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, that is really interesting I will play with that a bit and see if I can get something out of it.. if so I'll post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks very much to all the comments which progressively got me further to understanding the fano plane. To finally resolve this OldJohn suggested just count all the symmetries using the fact that every two points determine a unique line!

In the second diagram: Take one point anywhere 7 choices, then another point anywhere 6 choices, that determines a line - without loss of generality we can take that line to be the base of the triangle: Now there are 2x2 symmetries of the top part of the triangle. -- hardest part for me was realizing all the lines of the fano plane are actually circles. Therefore there are exactly 168 symmetries!